# How to replace text with dynamic content in InDesign CC 2017?

Tags: adobe-indesign

How can I replace a text with recurring dynamic content?

For Example: I have added text, *"Tutorial Example"*, as part of running paragraph in the document. In some pages there is one and in some there are more. I want to replace the text to *"Example 1"*, *"Example 2"* and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Type/Bulleted and Numbered Lists/Define Lists and click NEW. Name it Examples and uncheck "continue numbers from previous document in book." Click ok and ok to close the dialog.

Now create a new paragraph style and call it "Tutorial Examples". Open this new style and click on the Bullets and Numbering section. Set the list type to 'Numbers'. Set list to 'Examples'. In the Number Section type Example ^#. If you like you can create a character style here for how you want your dynamic text to display. Click ok.

Open Find/Change dialog. Under Find What: type "Tutorial Example". Under Change To: type a space. Under Change Format: Select the Paragraph Style you created called "Tutorial Examples" Click ok.

Now Click change all and it should replace Every occurrence of "Tutorial Example with a numbered list marker and a space. This assumes that each occurrence of "Tutorial Example" occurs in its own paragraph. If it is in line in a sentence then you will need to add a hard return (^p)after the space in your Change to: field.